# Sorting range of list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, sql-order-by

I was wondering if it is possible to do ranged sort using LINQ, for example i have list of numbers:

`List< int > numbers = new List< int >`

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 15   <-- sort
- 11   <-- sort
- 13   <-- sort
- 10   <-- sort
- 6
- 7
- etc.

Simply using `numbers.Skip(3).Take(4).OrderBy(blabla)` will work, but it will return a new list containing only those 4 numbers. Is is somehow possible to force LINQ to work on itself without returning a new "partial" list or to receive complete one with sorted part?
Thanks for any answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var partiallySorted = list.Where(x => x < 11)
                 .Concat(list.Where(x => x >= 11 && x <=15).OrderBy(/*blah*/)))
                 .Concat(list.Where(x => x > 15));
```

Comment: From Question: `Is is somehow possible to force LINQ to work on itself without returning a new list?` And what does `With` do different than `Concat`?

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I wanted to do except that i used "Concat" instead of "With" and it is working perfectly. Big thanks for this answer!

Comment: @Marduk doesn't *`"this is exactly what I wanted"`* contradict with *`"work on itself without returning a new list"`* ?

Comment: Well, maybe i didn't precise it (my english sux a bit) and it is returning a new list, but still result is exactly what i need. This is some workaround for LINQ to not be able to modify itself, so even if it is a new list, it's look like it was modifed.

Comment: I've just modified question to be more specific.

Comment: @L.B: Brain fart, you're absolutly right; there is no difference.

Answer (score 4):

```
List<int> list = new List<int>() {1,2,3,15,11,13,10,6,7};
list.Sort(3, 4,Comparer<int>.Default);
```

Comment: This isn't what i want, in my real life project I am not using numbers but custom class and i want to know if it is possible to use LINQ for that. I've just wrote sample list of numbers to simplify my question.

Comment: @Marduk No you can't do it with linq but you can write a custom `IComparer<CustomClass>` for your class  to use in "Sort"

Comment: Wow, I've never stumbled upon this overload of `List<>.Sort()`. This is a very elegant solution.

Comment: Be aware that List<T>.Sort is not stable. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ce6t5ad(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Simply get the required range based on some criteria and apply the sort on the resultant range using Linq.

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 15, 4, 1, 3, 2, 11, 7, 6, 12, 13 };
var range = numbers.Skip(3).Take(4).OrderBy(n => n).Select(s => s);
// output: 2, 3, 7, 11
```

Comment: Like i said, it will return new list with only 4 numbers, what im trying to do is to sort those 4 numbers from my entire list of numbers and place them back into that list. So in your example output should be like this: 15, 4, 1, 2, 3, 7, 11, 6, 12, 13

Answer (score 0):

No, the Linq extension methods will never modify the underlying list. You can use the method [`List<T>.Sort(int index, int counter, IComparer<T> comparer)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ce6t5ad.aspx) to do an in-place sort:

```
var list = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 15, 11, 13, 10, 6, 7};
list.Sort(3, 4, null);
```

Comment: So, if it is not possible to modify underlying list, maybe it is possible to return a new list containing a sorted records?

Answer (score 0):

Use this for default inline List Sort:

Syntax: List.Sort(start index, number of elements, Default Comparer)

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 15, 11, 13, 10, 6, 7 };
numbers.Sort(3, 6, Comparer<int>.Default);
```

If you want to sort by [properties/attributes] of the element or precisely something else use the below method,

I had sorted the string by number of characters, and also from 2nd element to end of List.

Syntax: List.Sort(start index, number of elements, Custom Comparer)

```
List<string> str = new List<string> { "123", "123456789", "12", "1234567" };
str.Sort(1, str.Count - 1, Comparer<string>.Create((x, y) => x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length)));
```