# Sorting a list alphabetically with lambda after a certain position

Tags: c#, list, sorting, lambda

Given a list with three elements that must stay at the top always:

```
Stay@Top1
Stay@Top2
Stay@Top3
Chicken
Bull
Zebra
Elephant
Hippo
```

Using lamdba expression, how can you sort this list alphabetically starting with "Chicken", and keeping the first three elements at the top?

Thanks ahead of time for any hints!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874947/sorting-range-of-list-using-linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
list.Take(3).Concat(list.Skip (3).OrderBy (x => x.Name))
```

Comment: I guess I assumed he was working with a `DbSet`. Can take it or leave it.

Comment: If he were, then first off you probably wouldn't want to do this.  Many query providers would be able to turn this whole thing into one efficient query, rather than your code which will perform 2 db queries.  If your db provider can't convert that into a single query and your goal is to ensure that the `Concat` is performed using linq to objects then you should use `AsEnumerable`.  It achieves that goal without the performance cost of creating a list and iterating the sequence, and it also semantically represents the goal you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Servy that makes sense, in either case I just tested this on LINQPad and the data return did not sort the second part correctly, in fact it looks like the sort is not even working.

Comment: This works, thanks very much for your contribution!  Turns out, I had to add ToList() to the end of this anyway because I was passing my list by ref to a function :)

Answer (score 6):

Take the three first items and then concatenate with the sorted remainder.

```
lst.Take(3).Concat(lst.Skip(3).OrderBy(s=>s);
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this works with the addition of ToList() due to passing the list into a function by reference.

Answer (score 1):

Given a `List<T>` where you wish to sort it but keep the first three elements at the start, you can use the overload of [`List<T>.Sort(int index, int count, IComparer<T> comparer)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ce6t5ad.aspx) which lets you specify the range of elements to sort.

So you could do (assuming `List<string>`):

```
lst.Sort(3, lst.Length - 3, Comparer<string>.Default);
```

This doesn't use a lambda like you asked for - but I don't see why you need to use a lambda. ;)

An in-place sort is going to be much more efficient, if you can use it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!  I decided to go with a different answer, but your approach is quite interesting!

Answer (score 1):

```
var final = lst.Take(3).ToList(); ;

var sortedSet = lst.Skip(3).OrderBy(x => x);

final.AddRange(sortedSet);
```

Comment: I am trying each method suggested in this thread, and this one is the first one that I got to work properly.  Thank you sir for your contribution!